# Multidimensional arrays in PHP - how to add values using foreach

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array defined as follows

`$SquadList = array('name', 'position', 'dob', 'nation', 'games', 'goals', 'assists');`

I'm looping through several foreach loops and storing data from JSON

```
foreach ($season as $key => $squad){
$SquadList[0] = $squad['full_name'];
$SquadList[1] = $squad['position'];
$SquadList[2] = gmdate("d-m-y", $birthday);
$SquadList[3] = $squad['nationality'];
$SquadList[4] = $squad['appearances_overall'];
$SquadList[5] = $squad['goals_overall'];
$SquadList[6] = $squad['assists_overall']; }

foreach ($season1 as $key => $squad){
$SquadList[0] = $squad['full_name'];
$SquadList[1] = $squad['position'];
$SquadList[2] = gmdate("d-m-y", $birthday);
$SquadList[3] = $squad['nationality'];
$SquadList[4] = $squad['appearances_overall'];
$SquadList[5] = $squad['goals_overall'];
$SquadList[6] = $squad['assists_overall'];
```

The code is messy. The output is only 2 elements when it should be 30+

I've tried `array_push` as follows

`array_push($SquadList['name'], $squad['full_name'];`

Comment: `$SquadList = array('name', 'position', 'dob', 'nation', 'games', 'goals', 'assists');` is not a multidimensional array. Maybe you meant it as an array of such arrays?

Comment: I’m running into several “wait— what?” things: 1) `$SquadList` is just a simple array. You probably mean `$squadList[] = ` 2) You’re overwriting `$SquadList` on every iteration of $season. You probably mean `$squadList[] = [$squad['full_name'], $squad['position'], ... ];` 3) It would be far easier to simply use `json_decode()` 4) if seasons were an array, you could simply loop through them, too, without writing the same code over and over and over

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if i get the question correctly, but i imagine you want it to be structured something like this:

```
$SquadList = []; // define it as an array
$ctr = 0; // define a counter that would be used in the two iterations

foreach ($season as $key => $squad){
    $SquadList[$ctr][0] = $squad['full_name'];
    $SquadList[$ctr][1] = $squad['position'];
    $SquadList[$ctr][2] = gmdate("d-m-y", $birthday);
    $SquadList[$ctr][3] = $squad['nationality'];
    $SquadList[$ctr][4] = $squad['appearances_overall'];
    $SquadList[$ctr][5] = $squad['goals_overall'];
    $SquadList[$ctr][6] = $squad['assists_overall'];
    $ctr++; // increase counter
}

foreach ($season1 as $key => $squad){
    $SquadList[$ctr][0] = $squad['full_name'];
    $SquadList[$ctr][1] = $squad['position'];
    $SquadList[$ctr][2] = gmdate("d-m-y", $birthday);
    $SquadList[$ctr][3] = $squad['nationality'];
    $SquadList[$ctr][4] = $squad['appearances_overall'];
    $SquadList[$ctr][5] = $squad['goals_overall'];
    $SquadList[$ctr][6] = $squad['assists_overall'];
    $ctr++; // increase counter
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that. How would I display every iteration of `$squad['full_name']`? Calling `print_r($SquadList[0]);` calls the first record only.

Comment: if you have followed any our answers, `print_r($SquadList[0]);` should be displaying all the items of the first record, not just the first `full_name` value. if you just want to display every iteration of the squad's full name, you can do something like `foreach($SquadList as $squad) { print_r($squad['full_name']); }`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you had two results is because you got the last squad for each season. This happened because each time a season iterated, it overwrote the previous squad.

To solve this problem, `$SquadList` must be an array. But you have to assign all its members at once, otherwise the array will increment every time you add a member.

#### Populating an array of arrays

```
foreach ($season as $key => $squad) {
    $squadList[] = [
        $squad['full_name'],
        $squad['position'],
        gmdate("d-m-y", $squad['birthday']),
        $squad['nationality'],
        $squad['appearances_overall'],
        $squad['goals_overall'],
        $squad['assists_overall']
    ];
}
```

Note a couple of changes I made:

1. I removed the capitalization on `$squadList` because convention has starting with a capital indicating an object, not a plain old variable
2. `$birthday` was undefined, so I made an educated guess

#### Cleaning up the code

You mentioned that “the code is messy”.  That is a very healthy observation to make.

What you are noticing is the result of two things:

1. Your code is repeating itself (a violation of DRY - Don’t Repeat Yourself)
2. Need to follow convention of PSR-12

So let’s get rid of the code duplication

#### Refactoring

When you start repeating yourself, that’s a signal to pull things into a function

```
function buildSquad(array $season)
{
   foreach ($season as $key => $squad) {
        $squadList[] = [
            $squad['full_name'],
            $squad['position'],
            gmdate("d-m-y", $squad['birthday']),
            $squad['nationality'],
            $squad['appearances_overall'],
            $squad['goals_overall'],
            $squad['assists_overall']
        ];
    }
    return $squadList;
}

$squadList = [];

// if you just want to lump them all together
$squadList[] = buildSquad($season);
$squadList[] = buildSquad($season2);
// etc
```

Comment: Thanks. This code returns nothing when I include an IF statement to only pull data from the JSON txt file that is defined in a variable `$clubId`

Example:

`function buildSquad(array $season)
{
   foreach ($season as $key => $squad) {
    if ($clubID == $squad['club_team_id'] or $clubID == $squad['club_team_2_id']):
        $squadList[] = [...`

My code uses `file_get_contents` to pull JSON data from txt files. Then I'm reading those files one by one and pulling relevant data.

Comment: What's `$clubID`?  That's not in your OP.  It certainly won't work in the scope of the function unless you pass it into the function.  The only outside data the function knows about is `$season`, since it is passed in.